# Custom Function Google Sheets that displays a message containing a value from another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

I have been working on this function and would love to display the value of a particular cell in the message that pops up.

This cell is in the same row as the "current cell" if that is of any help, I am just very lost and not even sure if this is possible.

```
function my2ndFunction() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Do you want to start?', '', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var output;
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    cell.setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add another alert message within the if condition like that:

```
function my2ndFunction() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Do you want to start?', '', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var output;
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    cell.setValue(new Date());
    ui.alert('The current date is: ' + new Date())
  }
}
```